# What are the rules of specification of size?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Even though i already specified the size of a variable, i don't understand why i should do it again when using an operation.

```
segment .bss
_n resd 1
_m resd 1

segment .text
mov **dword**[_n], 10
```

Would you give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many other assemblers you wouldn't have to specify the size again. This is a design choice of NASM. See [section 2.2.3 of the manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10.07/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.3):

> NASM, by design, chooses not to remember the types of variables you declare. Whereas MASM will remember, on seeing `var dw 0`, that you declared var as a word-size variable, and will then be able to fill in the ambiguity in the size of the instruction `mov var,2`, NASM will deliberately remember nothing about the symbol var except where it begins, and so you must explicitly code `mov word [var],2`.

The reason for this, is one of their design goals was that you should be able to look at a single line of NASM code and still tell exactly what machine code it would generate (where possible). If you just did `mov [_n],10` without a type specifier, you wouldn't know what that was going to generate without referring back to where `_n` was originally defined.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know Nasm doesn't remember the size of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov **dword**[_n], 10
```

The assembler needs to know the amount of memory to reserve for an operation and the left hand operand is used

```
mov al,[_n] should be ok even if [_n] is a dword
```

but

```
mov [_n], 10
```

tells the assembler nothing about size unless **dword** is used

After a while it becomes second nature to specify size in an asm program

Can also be useful for chopping up dwords into words and bytes, al will be loaded with the lowest byte in dword [_n]

You could also do mov word [_n],500000 and get a weird number because it's too big

but mov word [_n],eax would fail because eax is regarded as a dword

asm can be a bit quirky

Comment: I'm confused. You mean to tell me that the left hand operand is used for size specification? However, it doesn't make sense since the size of '[_n]' in 'mov [_n], 10' is already defined in segment .bss.

Comment: IMO if the size is not specified, the assmebler should take the declard size as default. I Don't see why you would have to specify it always manually. After all, whats the point of declaring the variable with a size?

Comment: Nasm has amnesia. Don't like it? Use Masm.

Comment: You have defined the size of *_n*, not *[_n]*.

Comment: The bottom line is: if you want a committee meeting become a social worker, if you want a solution accept the boundaries and become a programmer